Connection between independence conditions on multiplicative functions?
I am wondering if there is any connection between the coprimality condition on arithmetic multiplicative functions
$$f(ab) = f(a)f(b)\quad \text{if }(a, b) = 1,$$
and the independence condition on probability of two events occuring
$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)\quad \text{if }A, B\text{ independent}.$$
I found this post which suggests there could be some measure-theoretic way to unify the two ideas, but I am rather stumped beyond that. I also feel like statements of this form are more common to just number theory and probability (but I am drawing a blank).

The post you found has not even attracted comments imo because it lacks a lot of details. What is a ring of subsets? What is a "measure" on that ring? That it suggests another grand unification is  a gross exaggeration.
